# Round or ceil function in Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, catalyst

I need a value to be rounded in the Perl's Template Toolkit. But I am not able to use `ceil()`.

```
[%interestRate = ceil(mortgage.interest_rate / 100)%]
```

The answer shows a `null` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the syntax to provide `ceil` is

```
$c->stash->{ceil} = sub { ceil($_[0]) };

[% c.ceil(c.mortgage.interest_rate / 100) %]
```

But its usually better to do your calculations outside of templates.

```
$c->stash->{mortgagetInterestRate} = ...;
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you need division directive:

```
[% 15 / 6 %] -> 2.5

[% 15 div 6 %] -> 2

[% 15 mod 6 %] -> 3
```

> The div operator returns the integer result of division. Both % and
>   mod return the modulus (i.e. remainder) of division.

http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer a CPAN module, then look into `Template::Plugin::POSIX`. This module provides amongst others the `ceil` and `floor` functions:

```
[% USE POSIX -%]
[% POSIX.ceil(0.5) %]
[% POSIX.floor(0.5) %]
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

If last digit do not matter:

```
[% number FILTER format("%.2f"); %]
```